# Accessing android phone Camera thru USB from my java openCV application in real time

Tags: java, android, opencv, usb, computer-vision

I'm trying to learn computer vision with OpenCV and i need camera to work with but the only camera that i have is on my android phone.

**So im thinking about connecting it to my pc (via USB) and using it with my application. Is anything like that possible?** **Can i take information from camera connected via usb in real time?**

I have no experience with something like this. I know i can just record video ,save it,put it on my pc, and use it as resource -bud i would prefer to have real time *streaming* of video while my application will work in background on my desktop computer.

Will i have to code some android application to get this working?Or can i simple ask for that data from my desktop application?

Comment: look for an app, that can send an mjpeg stream, receive from that with a VideoCapture in your opencv java pc prog.

Comment: It sounds like you want to experiment programming with OpenCv on your PC, if that is the case, I'd look in to what berak suggested.  I wrote a client app on the Android device that connected to my PC via Wifi and then after receiving the images, I processed them and displayed them with imshow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to experiment and learn to use OpenCV, you can get an [IP Camera app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam&hl=en) for your phone and then read the image stream from your computer ([here's](http://robocv.blogspot.de/2012/01/using-your-ip-camera-with-opencv.html) an example of how to do that). That is the easiest "real time-ish" solution I can think of.

Comment: This looks promising.I will give this a shot!

Comment: Today i had time to test this and i guarantee this is really good solution so far.Thanks again McMa.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple way to use the a web cam (IP Webcam installed on my smartphone through Play Store) as camera using OpenCV and Java. Here is how: just copy the IP Webcam web link inside the Video Capture. Like this.

```
org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture webSource = new VideoCapture("http://192.168.43.1:8080/video");
```

The smartphone and the laptop should be inside the same Wi-Fi.